# Flexbox: How to make a containing div scale with the amount of text in a child?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a chat app and want to use flexbox to style the messages in the chat. However, when I use `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row` to get all of the divs in a line, the text part of the message overflows. How do I get the size of the parent div (of class `message`) to scale with the amount of text that is in `message-text` div?

```css
.message {
  margin-top: 1%;
  border-top: solid 1px lightgrey;
  padding: 1%;
}

.message-icon {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.message-name {
  width: 50px;
}

.message-text {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='message'>
  <div class='message-icon'></div>
  <div class='message-name'>Steve:</div>
  <div class='message-text'>THIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS
    IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS
    IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are no flex properties in your code. Please illustrate the problem.

Comment: you mean what by scale?

Answer (score -1):

You use flex on a container `.message` every first level child gets flexed in there `.message-*`

If you are new to flexing i highly recommend reading [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.message {
  margin-top: 1%;
  border: solid 1px lightgrey;
  padding: 1%;
  display: flex; /* added */
  flex-direction: row; /* added */
}

.message-icon {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.message-name {
  width: 50px;
}

.message-text {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 2%;
  display: inline-block; /* you dont need this, since its flexing anyways */
}
```

```html
<div class='message'>
  <div class='message-icon'></div>
  <div class='message-name'>Steve:</div>
  <div class='message-text'>THIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS
    IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGETHIS
    IS A MESSAGETHIS IS A MESSAGE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Feel free to comment my Downvoter - did i miss something?